# Configuring Outgoing email notifications in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-library

**My situation:** So I've configured the outgoing email in sharepoint 2010. We use a third party host for our email, mail.example.com, and I want email to send through that. I am guessing the hangup for notifications is either firewall or athentication related. I am completely lost.

**My Environment:** We are very small and have just 1 server running SBS 2011 and Sharepoint 2010. We access sharepoint using this url in a browser `http://servername:8888/websitename` any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue too and so I solve it and explain what I checked so hope this is usefull:

1. Check Outgoing email in central admin for correct config!
2. Check Firewall for allow port 8888 and port of your email server that send mail with that.
3. If your server is a virtual private network or etc that have any other firewall check them too ( this is my problem and I call them to allow my ports).

If You can send email with mail server directly to another Mail server this problem isnt firewall!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with firewall, as far as I can see that is. Every sign points to needing a "reciever connecter" which can easily be set up through exchange. Here's the trick I don't have exchange set-up on the server. We don't want to take the time to set that up and no one seems to have a solution for setting up a reciever connecter without using exchange server.